# Third Party Mail Sending Solution (Sendgrid/Sendmail/etc) vs using personal address by SMTP

Tags: php, email, smtp, mail

I know this is possible to send mail through "PHPMailer" by using SMTP of a personal address. (By creating a personal Gmail or yahoo address, and by using PHPMailer to send emails through this address in SMTP).

What is the deliverability rate of this sending method? Is it equal to a professional offer on a service like SendGrid?

When I send my mail from Gmail or Yahoo there are not blocked. Also by using Gmail in SMTP the result would be the same not?

(Edit : I speak about 10 000 mails sent in one day and not only transactional email.)

Comment: What volume of mail are you talking about?  Is the mail going to you (like from you contact form) or is it going to your customers (like transactional email about your website)?  Is there marketing email involved (newsletter)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller : I speak about 10 000 mails sent in one day.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a lot of experience with GMAIL, and am only partially qualified to answer but -

Quality dedicated providers will have a better deliverability rate then GMAIL - the focus of these specialist providers is deliverability.  Googles is selling adverts.  The deliverability depends on your recipients, what you are sending.

GMAIL claims to have sending limits (and indeed I'd have been surprised if this wasn't the case).  Although fairly generous, depending on how you send these emails you are likely to run into these - https://apps.google.com/supportwidget/articlehome?hl=en&article_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.google.com%2Fa%2Fanswer%2F166852%3Fhl%3Den&product_context=166852&product_name=UnuFlow&trigger_context=a